# What would be the correct statement in this cubic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\textrm{The problem is as follows:}$

$\textrm{The function f(x) is defined as:}$

$$f(x)=x^{3}-x+b$$

$\textrm{where x-intercept is (a,0)}$

Which of the following statements for $a$ and $b$ are correct?

$1.\,|a|<\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3},\,b=a(1-a^{2})$

$2.\,|a|>\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3},\,b=a(a^{2}-1)$

$3.\,|a|>\frac{9}{8},\,b=a(1-a^{2})$

$4.\,|a|<\frac{9}{8},\,b=a(a^{2}-1)$

$5.\,|a|>\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3},\,b=a(1-a^{2})$

What I tried to do was trying to plug-in the $a$ value on the function given in order to find a relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Since $(a,0)$ is the $x-intercept$

Therefore,

$$0=f(a)=a^{3}-a+b$$

$$a^{3}-a+b=0$$

$$b=a-a^{3}=a(1-a^{2})$$

But that's how far I went, the rest is where I'm stuck since I have no idea where do the square roots of $3$ and the other fractions come from. The answer I'm looking beyond the solution is one which could help me to understand how to get to those numbers or to understand why did they appear?.

Comment: Note that the problem implies that there is only 1 x-intercept. A cubic can have 1, 2 or 3 x-intercepts. You need to add a condition on $a$ so that there is only 1 x-intercept.

Comment: @CarlWoll The condition which must be added to $a$. Should it be greater and equal to zero or just greater than zero? (see on comments below). Regarding $a^2-4(a^{2}-1)\geqslant 0$ or $a^2-4(a^2-1)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $b=a-a^3$. You showed that yourself. Thus,$$\begin{aligned}[t]f(x) &= x^3-x+b \\ &=x^3-x+a-a^3\\&=(x^3-a^3)-(x-a)\\&=(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2-1).\end{aligned}$$
Set the latter quantity (which is $f(x)$) equal to $0$ and solve for $x$. You get $a$ for one solution (i.e., one $x$-intercept). Can you get the other one? (Hint: Quadratic formula.) When finding the other $x$-intercept, look to see what *must* be satisfied. (Hint: What you're taking the square root of must be nonnegative.)

Comment: It is glad to know I was not way off the answer but i'm still stuck at the solution. By following your directions I ended up on $x_{1,2}=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^{2}-4(b^{2}-1)}}{2}$. Then, since the square root must be non negative should be, $a^{2}-4(b^{2}-1)\geqslant 0,\, a^2\geqslant4(b+1)(b-1),\, a\geqslant \pm\sqrt{4(b+1)(b-1)},\, a\geqslant \pm 2(b+1)^\frac{1}{2}(b-1)^\frac{1}{2}.$ The last expression is where I ended up with but it does not seem to match any of the options. Moreover where does the absolute value come from?. Can you show more insight into this?.

Comment: Your answer should not involve $b$; no $b$ appears in the quantity of the last line of the displayed work in my answer. So use the quadratic formula again, but this time everything will involve only constants and $a$.

Comment: Sorry about that It was a typo I incurred when copying my progress in the comments. However by resolving that mistake I ended up with the following: $a^{2}-4(a^{2}-1)\geqslant 0,\, -3a^2\geqslant-4,\, a\leqslant \pm\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}},\, a\leqslant \pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}.$. It is the absolute value which I don't understand where does it come from?. Can you explain to me about this?. Moreover there is a less than equal to in the inequality is the part which I'm not sure if is correct in my judgement.

Comment: Also since solving a square equation yields two values. Which one should I choose?. Hope you can help me to clear these questions.

Comment: Still confused if what I've done is correct or not. Should I write $a^2-4(a^{2}-1)\geqslant 0$ or just $a^2-4(a^2-1)>0$ This is where I'm stuck at. Can you help clearning up my ideas?. The rest I believe is about the definition of the absolute value.